# Looking to concatenate specifc word in text

Tags: python, excel, text, nltk

I am looking to concatenate specific words in a text e.g. a text that reads

"I really hate **micro transactions**" OR
"I really hate **micro-transactions**"

should be converted to

"I really hate **microtransactions**"

I have been looking at excel functions and NLTK to do this, but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: What doesn't Replace (ctrl+H) doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

input.txt:

> I really hate micro transactions
> I really hate micro-transactions

Python code:

```
inputFile = open("input.txt","r+")
outputFile = open("output.txt","w")
for line in inputFile.readlines():
    line = line.replace('micro transactions', 'microtransactions')
    line = line.replace('micro-transactions', 'microtransactions')
    outputFile.write(line) 
inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

output.txt:

> I really hate microtransactions
> I really hate microtransactions

Now you just have to add some lines like `line = line.replace(...)` for whatever you want.